# How to correctly use the avogadro number?

Tags: stoichiometry

Avogadro constant, $N_A$ is equal to $\frac{6.02214076 \cdot 10^{23}}{mol}$. There is no unit of particle or anything in $N_A$ (nothing like $N_A = \frac{6.02214076 \cdot 10^{23} \ce {particles}}{mol}$). So like, can I Is it correct if I say

$$N_A=\frac{6.02214076 \cdot 10^{23}\ce{atom}}{mol}$$

if I'm doing stoichiometry in terms of atoms or

$$N_A=\frac{6.02214076 \cdot 10^{23}\ce{molecule}}{mol}$$

if I'm doing math in terms of molecules.

For example, $\ce{H2O}$ has the molecular mass of approximately $18.015u$ or $\frac{18.015u}{\ce{molecule}}$. I believe saying that the molecular mass of water is $\frac{18.015u}{molecule}$ is also a correct way of saying it. Though, I'd appreciate if someone can confirm this. If I want to convert from the molecular mass to molar mass, mathematically, it would be like such:

$$18.015u \cdot N_A = \frac{18.015u \cdot 6.022 \cdot 10^{23}}{\pu{mol}} = \frac{\pu{18.015g}}{mol}$$
or, I believe I can write like like such too:
$$\frac{18.015u}{\ce {molecule}} \cdot N_A = \frac{18.015u}{\ce{molecule}} \cdot \frac{6.022 \cdot 10^{23} \ce {molecule}}{mol}$$
The unit of molecule here will cancel out, leaving me with
$$\frac{18.015u \cdot 6.022 \cdot 10^{23}}{mol}$$
or since $6.022 \cdot 10^{23} \cdot 1u = 1$g,
$$\frac{18.015u \cdot 6.022 \cdot 10^{23}}{mol} \cdot \frac{1g}{6.022 \cdot 10^{23}u} = \frac{18.015g}{mol}$$
So my question is, can I add the "unit" particle in the $N_A$ formula like I showed before ($N_A = \pu{\frac{6.02214076 \cdot 10^{23}\ce{atom}}{mol}}$ or  $N_A = \pu{\frac{6.02214076 \cdot 10^{23} molecules}{mol}}$, etc)? If so, wouldn't I just changed the definition of $N_A$ or what $N_A$ equals to? Which I believe would be mathematically incorrect. Maybe I'm missing something. Also, can I say that the molecular mass of $\ce{H2O}$ is $\frac{\pu{18.015u}}{\pu{molecule}}$ instead of just $\pu{18.015u}$. I just hope to do the stoichiometry with the units right. I appreciate any help.

Comment: It goes as far back as to concept of abstract integer numbers, abandoning binding integers to real objects. No 3 rabbits, no 3 carrots, no 3 eggs, just 3. No Na atoms/mol, no Na ions/mol, no Na molecules / mol, just Na/ mol.

Comment: "There is no unit of particle or anything"... Although there is no a SI unit, the counting of particles is certainly within the definition of Amount of substance. Without particles, there is no Avogadro constant. The unit does not exist in my opinion just because it would be redundant (it does not require any definition or standard as counting objects seems a natural skill. Indeed positive integers were called natural number). What you did is what we have in mind.

Comment: @Alchimista so it's still correct then? I can add and treat atoms, molecules, ions, etc in the avogadro number and molecular mass?

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali I think that if it helps you why not? Remember that it is unit with no dimensions, it is just us counting. If I would be your teacher it will be fine for me. Otherwise just think of it, and don't write it down, if this thread is of practical relevance for your exercises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it correct if I say ...

There are two questions you have to consider:

1. Do you obtain the correct answer using this notation?
2. Are you using formally correct technical language?

The answer to the first question depends on whether you understand what you are doing - no matter which notation you decide to use. The answer to the second question is no. "Molecules", "Particles", "Carbon", "Atom" are all not part of the official SI units, so you would not use this notation in a formal document. In fact, "u" is not even part of the SI unit system (It is one of the "Non-SI units whose values in SI units must be obtained experimentally", https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure).

#### Adding annotations to units in general

Introductory textbooks sometimes add annotations to units as a way to explain stoichiometry and unit conversion. Here is one example:

$$\require{cancel}
0.75~\cancel{\mathrm{mol}~\ce{C3H8}} \times \frac{3~\cancel{\mathrm{mol}~\ce{CO2}}}{1~\cancel{\mathrm{mol}~\ce{C3H8}}} \times \frac{6.022 \times 10^{23}~\ce{CO2}~\text{molecules}}{\cancel{\mathrm{mol}~\ce{CO2}}} $$ $$= 1.4\times 10^{24}~\ce{CO2}~\text{molecules}$$

The formal way to write this would be:

$$\begin{align}
N_\mathrm{A}  &= \pu{6.02214076E-23 mol-1} \\
n_\ce{C3H8}   &= \pu{0.75 mol} \\
\nu_\ce{CO2}  &= 3 \\
\nu_\ce{C3H8} &= 1 \\[10pt]
N_\ce{CO2}    &= n_\ce{C3H8} \cdot \frac{\nu_\ce{CO2}}{\nu_\ce{C3H8}} \cdot N_\mathrm{A} \\
              &= \pu{0.75 mol} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \pu{6.02214076E-23 mol-1} \\
              &= \pu{1.35E24}
\end{align}$$

Here, the annotations are added to the quantity symbols (not to the units), and the units are the official SI units. Obviously, the formal way of writing it is more abstract, and in this case requires more space.

On the other hand, the formula used is quite expressive, and would apply no matter what the specific quantities are:

$$N_\ce{CO2} = n_\ce{C3H8} \cdot \frac{\nu_\ce{CO2}}{\nu_\ce{C3H8}} \cdot N_\mathrm{A}$$

It would roughly translate into: To get the number of carbon dioxide particles that are formed from a certain amount of propane, you take the amount of propane, multiply by the ratio of stoichiometric coefficients and by Avogadro's constant. Notice that the way the textbook shows the problem solution, it never mentions the names of the quantities that are used, but instead describes them using units and additional annotation only. Notice also that you would not "cancel out" the symbol $\ce{C3H8}$ because that would make the formula less meaningful.